# How to ETL a table that contains Blob columns from one Oracle table to another using SSIS

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, blob, etl

We have a table that contains 50 rows of data.the table includes BLOB data types, we are trying to see if we can use SSIS to copy the data from table1 to table2 inclusing the BLOB columns as we have tried to use other methods but did not succeed.

The Blob columns contain Excel documents.

Is this possible? Is there an easier way to do it in SSIS?
If not possible as there an easier way to it on Oracle?

Comment: Are these 2 tables in the same database, or different databases?

Comment: This is two tables in the same Database